# Custom log adding in spring integration DSL

Tags: logging, spring-integration-dsl

I am new to Spring Integration and I am started with the DSL based flow in it. I am looking for how to log a custom log message in the DSL flow. I tried like this using the log operator

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow huIntegrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from("input").split(splitter -> splitter.delimiters(","))
        .log(m -> "this is the message to log"+m)
        .<String, String>transform(String::toUpperCase)
        .aggregate()
        .channel("output")
        .get();
}
```

But here I am doing the string append. I was looking for some option like the slf4j where we can log the variable using the {}. Can you please help me with the best practice

Answer (score 0):

The logging adapter currently uses Apache Commons Logging, not slf4j.

You would either need to write a custom logging adapter, or use `String.format()`.